# Select by Attribute Sum Fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, sql, select-by-attribute

Is it possible to sum fields together in the select by attribute tool with a SQL query?

I'm working in ArcMap 10.3.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Please [edit] your question to give details of what you're trying to do, a bit of info about your data, and what you've tried.  What would summing field values together in a Select by Attributes do?  Usually you use a field calculator if you're trying to run calculations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to select features based on 3 fields, if [Field 1] + [Field 2] = [Field 3], you can do a query that says exactly that.  Put `field1 + field2 = field3` into the `WHERE` clause (where field1 etc. are the names of your fields)

[image]

[image]

Or if you want to check that two fields add up to a specific value, eg if [Field 1] + [Field 2] = 57, again you just enter exactly that into the `WHERE` clause:

```
field1 + field2 = 57
```

Again, `field1` etc. refers to your field names, and `57` is the value the values from the two fields need to add up to in order to be selected.

[image]

[image]